# How to reset password in Cisco spark using API?

Tags: cisco

I want to reset the password for my cisco spark application using API. Using the REST API I am only able to get user, post user, delete and update user.

Answer (score 0):

In short *you can't*.

- Spark API docs: https://developer.ciscospark.com/resource-people.html
- How to change your password (manually):
  https://support.ciscospark.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1834768-change-your-cisco-spark-app-password?b_id=8722